# Tabulator Tables With ExpressJS

Tags: tabulator

I'm very new to developing and I am trying to get tabulator to work in a nodejs environment using expressjs. I've learned that I can't run the script on the client side because there is no require function available. I know there are ways around that but I figured I would try to run in on the server side. I've used express generator with `--view=pug`. I've added `div(id=example-table)` in the index.pug. I have installed tabulator tables using `npm install tabulator-tables`. I tried to use the following in app.js:

```
var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');

app.get('/', function() {
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:205,
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ 
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    ],
    rowClick:function(e, row){
        alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
  });

  var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
  ];

  table.setData(tabledata);
});
```

Does nothing. Site loads with the everything else in the layout.pug and index.pug and source file shows `<div id=example-table></div>`, so I know that part at least worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to Vue, got it working.

Comment: Congrats... I use Tabulator in my React app, and it works as expected. There is massive improvement of this library compared to version 3.5, which makes the integration with popular js frameworks a breeze. Its documentation is terrific. Among free data grid libraries, I think I could recommend it, at least, for giving it a try : it is featured rich and it still grows for improvement. Thanks Oli Folkerd for creating and maintaining this awesome library